# Profiling an OpenGL 2.0 game coded in C++ with the entry project being in C#, all in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, c++-cli

So we have developped a game in c++/opengl 2.0 for school, and it's pretty laggy right now on some computers. I will first note that opengl 2.0 was forced on us by the University.

We would like to understand what is going on, to find the source of the lag and correct it.

We have noted that the game is laggy mostly in computers with a bad graphics card, (even if the processor and the ram are very strong), although that is not saying much.

We would like to know which tools should be used to know, for exemple, how much memory on the graphics card is being used, and also maybe, how much time is being spent on each function.

Comment: You could manually log times before method call and after the control returns, start on those lines.

Comment: Have you check the video driver? It must be only from the video card manufacturer site, not the default/Microsoft one. Also note, that OpenGL 2.0 is buggy on many Intel cards, especially old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rendering is the bottleneck you could try using the OpenGL [gDEBugger](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/gDEBugger/) tool to try and work out where your hotspots are.

[3DMark](http://www.3dmark.com/) may also be useful to find out how much graphics capability machines have relative to one another.